# Error when extracting features(spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I encountered some problems when I tried to extract features from raw data.

Here is my data:

```
25,Private,226802,11th,7,Never-married,Machine-op-inspct,Own-child,Black,Male,0,0,40,United-States,0
```

and here is my code:

```
val rawData = sc.textFile("data/myData.data")
val lines = rawData.map(_.split(","))
val categoriesMap = lines.map(fields => fields(1)).distinct.collect.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

Here is the error info:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

I want to extract the second column as the categorical feature, but it seems that it cannot read the column and leads to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
I tried many times but still cannot solve the problem.

---

```
val categoriesMap1 = lines.map(fields => fields(1)).distinct.collect.zipWithIndex.toMap
val labelpointRDD = lines.map { fields =>
    val categoryFeaturesArray1 = Array.ofDim[Double](categoriesMap1.size)
    val categoryIdx1 = categoriesMap1(fields(1))
    categoryFeaturesArray1(categoryIdx1) = 1 }
```

Comment: The reason why you might not be able to read is that your csv might have missing values. Try to investigate the size of your arrays after you split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for the example you supplied - which means it's fine for "valid" rows - but your input probably contains some invalid rows - in this case, rows with no commas.

You can either clean your data or improve the code to handle these rows more gracefully, for example using some default value for bad rows:

```
val rawData = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "25,Private,226802,11th,7,Never-married,Machine-op-inspct,Own-child,Black,Male,0,0,40,United-States,0",
  "BAD LINE"
))

val lines = rawData.map(_.split(","))
val categoriesMap = lines.map {
  case Array(_, s, _*) => s // for arrays with 2 or more items - use 2nd
  case _ => "UNKNOWN"       // default
}.distinct().collect().zipWithIndex.toMap

println(categoriesMap) // prints Map(UNKNOWN -> 0, Private -> 1)
```

**UPDATE**: per updated question - assuming these rows are indeed invalid, you can just skip them entirely, both when extracting the categories map and when mapping to labeled points:

```
val secondColumn: RDD[String] = lines.collect {
  case Array(_, s, _*) => s // for arrays with 2 or more items - use 2nd
  // shorter arrays (bad records) will be ~~filtered out~~
}

val categoriesMap = secondColumn.distinct().collect().zipWithIndex.toMap
val labelpointRDD = secondColumn.map { field =>
  val categoryFeaturesArray1 = Array.ofDim[Double](categoriesMap.size)
  val categoryIdx1 = categoriesMap(field)
  categoryFeaturesArray1(categoryIdx1) = 1
  categoryFeaturesArray1
}
```

Comment: @C.Y.Wu this is what I meant.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: @eliasah sorry, may I ask an extra question: how can I get the feature as a String if there exists invalid rows in my data?

Comment: @C.Y.Wu I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @eliasah Like I want to take the second column, which returns the String "Private", but if I use lines.map(fields => fields(2)), a error will occur...

Comment: Why don't you use spark-csv instead ? and deal with missing data using it.

Comment: @C.Y.Wu the solution is right here in this answer... you even accepted it. What's missing? :/

Comment: @TzachZohar your answer is correct but it drops the line with the missing data. (I upvoted your answer)

Comment: what else do you think OP would like to do with that line?

Comment: The OP seem to want keeping the missing label line's features.

Comment: @TzachZohar
 I edited my question, and added the code I wrote in my program. The last 5 lines are the original code. I have revised my code by the way you gave me in line 1. But there is still a problem in the line 4, so I wonder how to replace "fields(1)" with the String from column 2 if there might be some invalid rows in my data.

Comment: @C.Y.Wu I don't undestand. You've accepted the answer and use the old code you were using and now what's the question again ? If the answer solved your question and you have a new one, please ask it in a different thread !

Comment: @eliasah is right, but I've edited my answer per what I think your (new) question is. Hope it helps, if not - do open another question.

Comment: @eliasah I just don't know how to revise the line 4 because an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will occur if I use the original code. So I hope to know how can I do to pass the String instead of using fields(1) in line 4. Sorry, I didn't state my question clearly.

Comment: @TzachZohar It's exactly what my problem is. I got it, thank you!